# How to set system time in linux using time_t variable

Tags: c++, c, ntp

I have a time_t variable, I want to set system time (linux) using this variable. 
lets say,

```
time_t tmp;
```

I know that I can print this time using ***ctime(&tmp)***, and output would be like this.

```
Tue Jan 13 15:54:47 2015
```

how can I use this tmp variable to set my system time?

EDIT:
This question is not a duplicate of question marked by moderator. For answer, please refer comment section.

Comment: something like `settimeofday()`?

Comment: `settimeofday()` is the right answer, the duplicate question pointed is not a duplicate, it answer different question.